# Referencing MongoDB ObjectIDs in React with hooks causes TypeError: Cannot read property '$oid' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, objectid

I appear to have an issue accessing the ObjectID string returned by MongoDB when referenced as part of the useSelector React hook, but it is not an issue elsewhere in the same application.  Is there an issue with the $ symbol in the key name?

my api call returns this

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "5e121d3d52d781668fbc619c"}, "name": "Foo Document Name"}
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { setFoo } from '../../actions';

function FooInfo(props) {
 const foo = useSelector(state => state.foo);
 console.log('after useSelector', foo);
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 useEffect(function() {
   console.log('useEffect', props.match);
   axios.get(`/api/foo/${props.match.params._id}`, {headers: {'content-type': 'application/json’}})
     .then(function(response) {
       dispatch(setFoo(response.data));
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
       console.log('error', error);
     });
 }, [dispatch, props]);

 return (
   <div>
     <h2>{foo.name}</h2>
     <small>id: {foo._id.$oid}</small>
     <hr/>
   </div>
 )
}
```

from actions/index.js

```
…
export const SET_FOO = 'SET_FOO’;
export function setFoo(foo) {
 return {
   type: SET_FOO,
   foo: foo,
   _id: foo._id.$oid
 };
};
```

I know this line works `_id: foo._id.$oid` because the console.log after the useSelector line shows:

```
after useSelector 
    • {_id: {…}, name: “Foo Document Name"}
        • _id:
            • $oid: "5e121d3d52d781668fbc619c"
            • __proto__: Object
        • name: "Foo Document Name"
        • __proto__: Object
```

And the action object holds:

```
action     
    • {type: "SET_FOO”, foo: {…}, _id: "5e121d3d52d781668fbc619c"}
        • type: "SET_FOO"
        • foo:
            • _id: {$oid: "5e121d3d52d781668fbc619c"}
            • name: "Foo Document Name"
            • __proto__: Object
        • _id: "5e121d3d52d781668fbc619c"
        • __proto__: Object
```

The browser give this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$oid' of undefined
```

If I remove the .$oid from     id: {foo._id.$oid}   I receive this error in the browser:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$oid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

foo._id cannot be undefined as removing the .$oid demonstrates that foo._id contains something.

This looks like a problem with react hooks to me but I am a novice so I don’t trust my perspective here.  I believe this might be the case because changing the useSelector line to:
const [foo, tempID] = useSelector(state => [state.foo, state.foo._id.$oid]); gives the TypeError as well.

Comment: the error in the console is from before the data come from the axios. till then the `foo._id` is undefined, and not an object. so you cannot do `foo._id.$oid`

Comment: If I remove the line that reads <small>id: {foo._id.$oid}</small>, the code works and the {foo.name} appears in the browser, so I know that foo is populated prior to the <small>id: {foo._id.$oid}</small> line.

Comment: `foo.name` is undefined before you get the data from the api, but there is no problem to output `undefined`. the problem is when you trying get property from undefined, as it was n object. before you get data from the api the `foo._id` is undefined, and you trying to get the property `$oid`from it. it is the problem

Comment: Try something like `{foo._id? foo._id.$oid: null}`

Comment: That did the trick!